# How can I display all the HTTP Headers when using the DefaultHTTPClient?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

When using the `DefaultHttpClient()` from the Apache Commons HTTP Client, is it possible to show the full request in the console output for debugging purposes?

I'm having issues with my application and I feel that the easiest way to debug it it would be to inspect all data sent by the `DefaultHTTPClient`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From another answer on StackOverflow. This can easily be done by enabling the debug logging for the Apache HTTP Client:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.headers").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);

System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime", "true");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire", "debug");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http", "debug");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.headers", "debug");
```

Comment: I inserted this code, but I get no extra logging from this.
Is there anything else I have to do that this works.

Comment: It also did not work for me

Answer (score 17):

You can get all headers like this:

```
Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
  String headerName = (String)headerNames.nextElement();
  out.println("" + headerName);
  out.println("" + request.getHeader(headerName));
}
```

See [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20120831110929/http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Request-Headers.html) for more info.

Comment: Update from the future: `request.getAllHeaders()` returns an empty array.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, here's sample code:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import org.apache.http.Header;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
    ...
    HttpResponse response;
    ...
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(serviceURL);
    response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
    ...
    // Print all headers
    List<Header> httpHeaders = Arrays.asList(response.getAllHeaders());        
    for (Header header : httpHeaders) {
        System.out.println("Headers.. name,value:"+header.getName() + "," + header.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: The OP wanted the Request, and not the Response headers.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the request you are passing somewhere HttpRequest object. It has method `getAllHeaders()`

Comment: This results an empty array for `HttpGet` objects.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using *Logback* as your logging framework, add the following configuration to your `logback.xml` / `logback-test.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration scan="true">

    <!-- more config -->

    <logger name="org.apache.http" level="DEBUG"/>

    <!-- more config -->

</configuration>
```

Having added this configuration, Logback's log appenders will now show useful HttpClient-related information about HTTP request and response headers, among other things.