# How to show the result of debug logger on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, logging

How to make eclipse show the result of log? I am followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12381788/1799322) and I am stuck with showing log.

Comment: What logging framework are you using?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't prepare a logging framework on default? I didn't plugin anything yet into my eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logs are generally written to a log file. But if you want to see debugs on the console then you should use the console appender depending on the logger you are using.